# Align H1 to bottom right of DIV

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I have the following code to align my H1 to the bottom of the DIV:

CSS:

```
h1wrap{
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  width: 358px;
}
h1{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="h1wrap">
  <h1>title</h2>
</div>
```

This partially does what I want... if aligns the text of the header at the bottom of the div and aligns it to the right. But instead of the H1 filling out the first line as much as possible before wrapping to the next line, I want to fill out the last line first and work the way up...

So a title like "THIS IS A VERY LONG TITLE" that now would be wrapped to:

> ```
> THIS IS A VERY LONG
>               TITLE
> ```

Should be this:

> ```
>                 THIS
> IS A VERY LONG TITLE
> ```

I create this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rd3vzq48/) that has the code above and shows how for I got so far. A CSS solution would be perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no broadly-supported way to do this without changing your markup. If you can't use `writing-mode: rl-bt`, flex-box would be my next thought, but you'd have to make each word it's own element.

Probably not feasible, but just in case: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rd3vzq48/3/)

Markup:

```
<div class='h1wrap'>
  <h1><span>This</span> <span>Is</span> <span>A</span><span>Very</span> <span>Long</span> <span>Title</span></h1>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
h1{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

h1 span {
  margin: 0 2px; /* otherwise you loose the space between words */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSS solution, support may be limited as I can't find it on http://caniuse.com/ but its working for me now in IE...

Add this to your H1:
 `writing-mode: rl-bt`

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rd3vzq48/1/

Ref: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

Comment: elegant solution, but I'm concerned about the browser compatibility of this... it doesn't work for many mobile devices and FireFox/Safari don't support it at all... thanks for the answer though, would be great if this was supported across the browsers

Comment: Interesting reading on emulating this at http://www.zachleat.com/web/css3-text-writing-mode/

Comment: Thanks for the link - Its a shame that `rl-bt` is not on the emulate list.